# Making something rotate x more degrees in CSS

Tags: css, rotation, css-transforms

While experimenting with CSS transform functions, I tried to implement a feature that rotates an image 90 degrees each time a button is pressed:

```
$("#rotateClockwise").click(function(){

    $("#featuredImage").css("webkit-transform", "rotate(+90deg)");

});
```

However, I want the button in this example to rotate 90 *additional*  degrees each time the button is clicked -- the above code only rotates the image the first time that I click the button.  I know I can do this with some additional JS, but is there a way to implement 90 degrees additional rotation with just CSS transforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store angle in variable :)

```
var angle = 0;
$("#rotateClockwise").click(function(){
    angle = (angle + 90) % 360;
    $("#featuredImage").css("webkit-transform", "rotate(" + angle + "deg)");
});
```

edit:
AFAIK it's not possible with only CSS...